# the (char *) cast in list_entry() of the Linux Kernel linked list implementation

Tags: c

This is the macro definition:

```
/**
 * list_entry - get the struct for this entry
 * @ptr:    the &struct list_head pointer.
 * @type:   the type of the struct this is embedded in.
 * @member: the name of the list_struct within the struct.
 */
#define list_entry(ptr, type, member) \
    ((type *)((char *)(ptr)-(unsigned long)(&((type *)0)->member)))
```

I don't understand why ptr is casted to `(char *)`. Can't I just subtract the offset of `member` from `ptr`? Like this:

```
#define list_entry(ptr, type, member) \
        ((type *)((ptr)-(unsigned long)(&((type *)0)->member)))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Pointer arithmetic is equivalent to:

```
ptr[addend]
```

not

```
(ptr_type *)((unsigned long)&ptr + addend)
```

The latter requires an explicit cast to `char *` (as that is the unit of memory) to manipulate a pointer's value directly.

Comment: I think you meant `(unsigned long)&ptr`.